# Copy more excel shapes into powerpoint

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I have the following code which let me copy

```
Sub pptCopy()

Dim pptapp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim slide As PowerPoint.slide
Dim shape1 As PowerPoint.shape

var2 = "C:\Documents and Settings\aa471714\Desktop\Presentation2.pot"

Set pptapp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
Set ppt = pptapp.Presentations.Open(var2)
Set slide = ppt.Slides(2)
Set shape1 = slide.Shapes.Paste(1)

pptapp.Visible = True

Call copyExcel1

With shape1

.Left = 100
.Width = 100

End With

End Sub
```

And an another macro

```
Sub copyExcel1()

Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
Dim oWB As Workbook
Dim cht As Excel.ChartObject

var2 = "C:\Documents and Settings\aa471714\Desktop\Template.xls"
Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(var2)

oExcel.Visible = True

Sheets("Sheet5").ChartObjects("AchmeaBankNL").Chart.ChartArea.Copy


End Sub
```

I however have two issues:

- I want to move the excel picture to a specific place in powerpoint (fe shape 3)
- I want to copy more than excel figure (i need to copy 2, one to shape 3 and one to shape 4).

Does anybody know how I should edit code below to accomplish this?

Dear regards,

Marc

Answer (score 0):

First, you should edit the subject of your question; it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question itself.

To move the shape to a specific position in the "stacking" order, use something like this function:

```
Function ShapeToZOrder(oSh As Shape, lPosition As Long)
    oSh.ZOrder msoSendToBack
    Do Until oSh.ZOrderPosition = lPosition
        oSh.ZOrder msoBringForward
    Loop
End Function
```